# how to POST data to external URL in MVC4 using server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Simple question:

Now I have that form in my view:

```
<form action="https://www.xyz.com/xyz/ISO/NewPayment"
method="post" name="payform">

    <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="@Model.OrderId">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay">
</form>
```

It send POST data and redirect user to `https://www.xyz.com/xyz/ISO/NewPayment`.

So simple, but I want to check on server side correctness of that data, before user will be redirected to a external URL.

How can I do this in asp.net MVC? How can I send POST data from server side, and then redirect user?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Use the `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` on the server side to POST data. This works in any .net code, not just mvc.

Comment: could you give me an example, how can I use it in controller, where I have to return ActionResult? Regards

Comment: @fejesjoco I know this is old question/answer, but the example provided doesn't redirect the user to the external url/page afterward?